# Fetch from large DB doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this MySQL database with over a *million records*. I am not the owner of the database and dont have write/modify permissions to it. I have a small target db called `MyDB` that fetches some fields from the giant view. Now these are the problems I face working with the huge million-record table on *MysqlWorkbench*..

```
GiantDB(MySQL database)

--gview(over a million records. No permissions to write)

+id(PK)
+name-String
+marks-Integer
+country-String

myDB(Target SQLite DB)

--mytable

+id(PK)
+name-String
```

So this is a rough sketch of these two databases. I am not able to query gtable without setting row limits(to 1000).

`count(*)` doesnt work either.

***My ultimate goal is to insert the million names into myTable from gtable.***

Inserting gView's fields into myTable takes forever, and automatically gets killed.
Any way of doing this efficiently?

I looked up and people were talking about indexes and stuff. I am completely clueless on what to do. A clear explanation would be of great help. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Are you copying every single row from gtable?

Comment: yeah.. Every single row is needed..

Comment: You need an id that has access to query "GiantDB" - talk to your manager - explain what you need and why you need it - explain why it's going to take "forever" otherwise.

Comment: I have access to query GiantDB.. Its just that I cant modify its schema

Comment: i edited my question just to clear up the confusion

Comment: Perhaps something to do with exceeding a packet size?

Comment: Is there timeout? Are you tring to insert each row after getting it from the big DB or you collect 500-1000 and then store them? Note that 1 mil records is not "giant" DB - it is relatively big but not giant. Post the query you are running.

Comment: I have no idea how big it is(1mil or more) since I am not able to run count() on it. But I know for certain that its over a million records. And,I am using the former method. Fetch and insert.

Comment: select name from gTable; I am inserting this into my SQLite table using SQLAlchemy.. Both the queries dont work..  Select takes forever and hangs, insertion is killed.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I have no idea what that means. :( Can you please elaborate?

Comment: "*Select takes forever and hangs*" seems like a timeout issue that @i486 mentioned. See: http://serverfault.com/questions/559887/mysql-select-query-hangs

Comment: Select hangs only if I remove the set row limit option in my MySqlWorkbench. It works well upto a certain limit say 10k..

Comment: Or a memory issue - but the problem here is that there is no error reported in the question, no code included to reproduce the problem and the OP has done no diagnostics of the problem. Please read the FAQ

Comment: Post the loop which transfers the records. Is it in PHP/Perl/Python or which lang?

Comment: Python.. SQLALchemy..
temp=DBSession.execute('select name from Gview')

        for x in temp:
        
           a=myTable(name=str(x.name))
           DBSession.add(a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A million rows is a medium sized table. Don't let its size throw you.)

From the comment thread it sounds like you're taking too long to read the result set from MySQL, because it takes time to create your rows in your output database.

Think of this as an export from MySQL followed by an import to sqlite.

The export you can do with MySQL Workbench's `export...` feature, which itself uses the `mysqldump` command-line tool.

You then may need to edit the .sql file created by the export command so it's compatible with sqlite.  Then import it into sqliite. There are multiple tools that can do this.

Or, if you're doing this in a program (a python program, perhaps) try reading your resultset from the MySQL database row by row and writing it to a temporary disk file.

Then disconnect from the MySQL database, open up your sqlLite database and the file, read the file line by like and load it into the database.

Or, if you write the file so it looks like this

```
1,"Person Name"
2,"Another Name"
3,"More Name"
```

etc, you'll have a so-called CSV (comma-separated value) file. There are many tools that can load such files into SQLlite.

Another choice: this will be mandatory if your MySQL database has very tight restrictions on what you can do. For example, they may have given you a 30-second query time limit.   **ASK your database administrator for help** exporting this table to your sqlite databse. Tell her you need a .csv file.

You should be able to say `SELECT MAX(id) FROM bigtable` to get the largest ID value.  **If that doesn't work the table is probably corrupt.**

One more suggestion:  fetch the rows in batches of, say, ten thousand.

```
SELECT id, name FROM bigtable LIMIT     0,10000

SELECT id, name FROM bigtable LIMIT 10000,10000

SELECT id, name FROM bigtable LIMIT 20000,10000

SELECT id, name FROM bigtable LIMIT 30000,10000   etc etc.
```

This will be a pain in the neck, but it will get you your data if your dba is uncooperative.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi this seems to be an excellent option but my select * statement hangs when I tried querying the view in Mysql Workbench without specifying limits. Will it work well if I do it programmatically?

Comment: Try doing `export` in Workbench rather than the query.

Comment: It says "error:Unhandled exception: built_in_fucntion_or_method" object has no attribute __getitem__

Comment: You're going to need help from your database administrator. The MySQL server you're working with is locked down too tightly for you to do what you need to do.

Comment: Is that why I am getting this error? :( I have only read permissions to this database I can run queries and then export. Is there any workaround for this since It jams only when I have to fetch the entirety of data. Chunks of data are queried  without any hassle.

Comment: Okay so I just read your edits. I should probably ask her for a .csv file of the data.. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: yes that might be an option if all else fails But is there any way I can get the count of records from this table? count(*) hangs

Comment: You should be able to say `SELECT MAX(id) FROM bigtable` to get the largest ID value. That's not exactly the COUNT(*), but it's reasonably close. **If that doesn't work the table is probably corrupt.**